# how add class in selected images in slide show?

Tags: javascript

When I click on thumb image, I want to selected that thumb image, but here when I click other thumb image previous thumb image remain selected

**CSS Code:**

```
.imgStyle:hover {
      border-color: black;
}
.imgStyle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
.active {
    border-color: red;
}
```

**//js code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divContainer img').on('click', function () {

        $(this).addClass('active');

        var imgURl = $(this).attr('src');

        $('#mainImage').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', imgURl);
        }).fadeIn(1000);

    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<img id="mainImage" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="540" height="500" style="border:3px solid grey">

<br/>
<div id="divContainer">
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Desert.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Koala.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Also add `$(this).siblings('img').removeClass('active');`

Comment: Now, total slide show is not working. and it is selecting all thumb image

Comment: Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/oL5r6tyo/)

Comment: Add `$('#divContainer img').removeClass('active');` before `$(this).addClass('active');`.

Comment: This working fine.
$('#divContainer img').removeClass('active');

here if i used 'this' instead of #divContainer img, it not working. Can you please me why?
Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove `active` class from `siblings` of the clicked image

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divContainer img').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('img').removeClass('active');
    var imgURl = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#mainImage').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', imgURl);
    }).fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.imgStyle:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
.imgStyle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
.active {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="mainImage" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="540" height="500" style="border:3px solid grey">
<br/>
<div id="divContainer">
  <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
  <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Desert.jpg" />
  <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
  <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
  <img class="imgStyle" src="images/Koala.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 var:

```
                Var currentslide;

                var oldSlide;
```

In the function add

```
 At the top :

                 OldSlide= currentSlide;

                CurtentSlide=$(this);
```

Then add the classe to currentSlide, 
And remove it from current slide.

Sorry for the sintax but i'm writing via phone.